# Unexpected scroll on single touch after panning in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, scroll, panning

I have extended `WebView` and I have enabled zooming with `myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);`.

When I tap the screen (single tap/touch) after I have panned, the `WebView` seems to move (scroll) to an other position. This messes up my panning and double tap events, because the coordinates change unexpectedly.

Is there a way to prevent this? Android version is 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause seems to be that the `onScroll` event is fired.

I've found a workaround by setting a boolean to false in every method (except `onScroll`) of my class that extends `SimpleOnGestureListener`, and then checking that boolean in `onScroll`. If it's false, then I return true to indicate that the event has been consumed.